# Errors when loading Fancybox jQuery, Javascript and Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to implement FancyBox v2.1.7 and I am receiving a few errors when trying to load the content. So I have followed the instructions and added the relevant code to the head tag of my php document. Please see code and images as reference:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.7"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

**Website errors**
[image: Website Errors]
I have name the folder fancybox on the server and I have positioned the code above in the head of my product.php page.

product code

```
<?php
$product_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Product_Title_Slug = '$seo_title'");

// If no match exists, display error 404
if (mysql_num_rows($product_sql) == 0)
{
    include('error404.php');
    exit();
}
$prod_row = mysql_fetch_array($product_sql);
$prod_id = $prod_row['Product_ID'];
$cat_id = $prod_row['Category_ID'];
$prod_title = $prod_row['Product_Title'];
$prod_meta_title = $prod_row['Product_Meta_Title'];
$prod_code = $prod_row['Product_Code'];
$prod_description = $prod_row['Product_Description'];
$prod_meta_description = $prod_row['Product_Meta_Description'];
$prod_meta_keywords = $prod_row['Product_Meta_Keywords'];
$prod_points = explode("|", $prod_row['Product_Points']);
$info_name = array("","Continuous KVA:","Maximum KVA:","Continuous KW:","Maximum KW:","Sockets:","Fuel Type:","Run Time:","Noise Level:","Weight:","Width:","Height:","Length:","Fuel Capacity:","Starting Method:","Frequency:","AVR:", "ATS:");
$info_type = array(""," KVA"," KVA"," KW"," KW","",""," hours"," dba @ 7m","kg","mm","mm","mm","L","","Hz","", "");
$price = $prod_row['Price'];
$price_sale = $prod_row['Price_Sale'];
$price_final = $prod_row['Price_Final'];
$prod_video = $prod_row['Product_Video'];
$offer = $prod_row['Offer'];
$next_day_del = $prod_row['Next_Day_Delivery'];
$stock = $prod_row['Stock'];
$prod_brand = $prod_row['Product_Brand'];
$warranty = $prod_row['Warranty'];
$brand_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE Brand_ID = $prod_brand");
if (mysql_num_rows($brand_sql) > 0)
{
    $brand_row = mysql_fetch_array($brand_sql);
    $brand_name = $brand_row['Brand_Name'];
}

// Get category details for breadcrumbs
$category_sql = mysql_query("SELECT Category_Name, Category_Name_Slug FROM categories WHERE Category_ID = $cat_id");
$cat_row = mysql_fetch_array($category_sql);
$cat_name = $cat_row['Category_Name'];
$cat_name_slug = $cat_row['Category_Name_Slug'];

// Assign page details
$page_title = $prod_title;
$meta_title = $prod_meta_title; 
$meta_description = $prod_meta_description;
$meta_keywords = $prod_meta_keywords;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?=$meta_title?> | <?=$site_name?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?=$meta_description?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?=$meta_keywords?>" />

<?php include ("includes/header-tags.php") ?>


<!--2017 Fancy-->
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.7"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tabs.js"></script>
<?php if (isset($_POST['Add_Basket'])): // Adding to basket ?>
<script src="/js/addbasketpopup.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
<link href="/css/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <?php include ("includes/header.php") ?>
    <ul id="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li> &rsaquo; <a href="/<?=$cat_name_slug?>"><?=$cat_name?></a></li>
        <li> &rsaquo; <?=$page_title?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php include ("includes/left-content.php") ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="prod-details-img">
            <?php
            if ($warranty >= 2) {
                echo '<div class="prod-details-warranty">' . $warranty . ' Years Warranty</div>';
            }
            ?>
            <div></div>
            <img src="/images/large/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" alt="<?=$prod_title?>" />
        </div>
        <div id="prod-details">
            <h1 class="prod-title-large"><?=$prod_title?></h1>
            <span id="prod-details-delivery">
            <img class="price-prom-sml" src="/images/price-promise.gif" alt="Price Promise" /><br />
            Price includes VAT &amp; Delivery<br />Order before 1pm for Free Next Day Delivery <br/>(UK Mainland Only)*</span>
            <div id="prod-details-buy">
                £<?=$price_final?>
                <?php if ($stock == "TRUE"):?>
                <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Auto_ID" value="<?=$prod_id?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="QTY" value="1" />
                    <button type="submit" name="Add_Basket" id="buy-btn">Buy</button>
                </form>
                <?php else: ?>
                <br />Out of Stock
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="product-specs">       
        <div id="tabContainer">
                <div id="tab_1" class="tabs_on" onclick="tabsClass.switchTab(this);">Description</div>
                <div id="tab_2" class="tabs_off" onclick="tabsClass.switchTab(this);">Specifications</div>
                <?php if(!empty($prod_video)): ?>
                <div id="tab_3" class="tabs_off" onclick="tabsClass.switchTab(this);">Video</div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="tab_1_data" class="tab_content">
                <p><?=nl2br($prod_description)?></p>
                <?php
                // If product has bullet points, explode and print
                if (!empty($prod_points[0]))
                {
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ($prod_points as $bullet_point)
                    {
                        echo '<li>' . $bullet_point . '</li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="tab_2_data" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                <table class="spec-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <?php if(!empty($brand_name)): ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Manufacturer:</td>
                      <td><?=$brand_name?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="150">Product Code:</td>
                      <td><?=$prod_code?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $class = ($x == 3) ? 'prod-result-last' : 'prod-result';
                    $x = 1;
                    while ($x <= 17):
                        if (!empty($prod_row["Info_$x"])):
                            if ($prod_row["Info_$x"] == "TRUE")
                            {
                                $prod_row["Info_$x"] = "Yes";
                            }
                            elseif ($prod_row["Info_$x"] == "FALSE")
                            {
                                $prod_row["Info_$x"] = "No";
                            }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?=$info_name[$x]?></td>
                      <td><?=$prod_row["Info_$x"] . $info_type[$x]?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        endif;
                    $x++;
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($warranty)): ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Warranty:</td>
                      <td><?=$warranty?> Year</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
               </div>
               <?php if(!empty($prod_video)): ?>
               <div id="tab_3_data" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                    <?=$prod_video?>
               </div>
               <?php endif; ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                tabsClass.addTabs("tabContainer");
            </script>
        </div>
        * Next Day Delivery subject to stock, please see our <a href="/terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.
    </div>
    <?php include ("includes/footer.php") ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have this running on a server where I can look at the code?

Comment: @StefanBurt Yes I do have this running on a server. What code specifically do you require to see? Kind regards.

Comment: Working code so I can assess what the issue is. It's really hard to know what the issue is without seeing what's happening or not. If you have a sensitive system then maybe exact the code using sitesucker or similar program and then supply that code.

Comment: @StefanBurt I have added the code you requested

Comment: To diagnose the issues if you run the code in the browser then do a view source.  Find for example this Js file.

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

If your running it under a local environment you might have a url which is 
http://localhost, check the file by copying and pasting the path like so:

http://localhost/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js

Or try Chrome developer tools and then go to the network tab, click 'JS' to just filter these results then check each file to see if they're any 404s.

Answer (score 0):

I guess (since you did not gave a link to live page) that files do not have correct path, therefore they contain 404 error message or something like that and therefore you see these messages.

Check your paths, try using direct paths, e.g. `src="/fancybox/` instead of `src="fancybox/`

Comment: I believe the error 'syntaxerror: expected expression, got < ' is due to what your suggesting which is a result being returned as a 404 page which will be HTML hence the '<'.

Comment: I have checked and amended the paths and still I have this error message. I am a little confused as there are no syntax errors either. :/

Comment: Have you used developer tools to check if files are loaded correctly?